# Variable's value of JS Closure

Tags: javascript, variables, closures

Could you please try to explain me how does it work that variable `i` isn't re-initialized to zero value when function `a` is called for the second time. Thank you

```
var a = (function () {
    var i = 0;
    return function () {return i += 1;}
})();

a();
a();
```

Comment: Because `a` doesn't contain the logic to set `i = 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `a` isn't the function in which `i` is declared in the `var` statement. Instead, `a` is the function that that function *returns* when it is called during the initialization of `a`. Thus, `a` is the function

```
function() { return i += 1; }
```

The `i` in that function refers to the `i` that was in the enclosing anonymous function. It is essentially a persistent value that the `a` function can reference (and modify) each time it is called.

Comment: So if I get it right, I should think of the "i" variable as it's declared outside of "a" function ( and it's something like global variable )?

Comment: @M_V yes, in that function `i` is "relatively global".  It's not declared in that function, but it's available in the *closure* formed when that outer anonymous function was called.